# Removing a duplicate JQuery library in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress site which uses a plugin allowing the easy addition of popup windows from the click of a button. Was working fine but now I get an error each time the popup button is clicked. In addition to the error, the popup no longer appears. Instead the scroll bar disappears and the page freezes. It’s as if an invisible popup has loaded.

I hit f12 and captured an error when the button was clicked:

```
Uncaught TypeError: f.getClientRects is not a function
at r.fn.init.offset (jquery-3.2.1.min.js?ver=4.8.2:4)
at Object.getWithinInfo (position.min.js?ver=1.11.4&nocache=1:11)
at r.fn.init.a.fn.position (position.min.js?ver=1.11.4&nocache=1:11)
at r.fn.init.reposition (site.min.js?defer&ver=1.6.6&nocache=1:1)
at r.fn.init.e.fn.popmake (site.min.js?defer&ver=1.6.6&nocache=1:1)
at r.fn.init.open (site.min.js?defer&ver=1.6.6&nocache=1:1)
at r.fn.init.e.fn.popmake (site.min.js?defer&ver=1.6.6&nocache=1:1)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (site.min.js?defer&ver=1.6.6&nocache=1:2)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js?ver=4.8.2:3)
at HTMLDocument.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js?ver=4.8.2:3)
```

I believe the issue relates to duplicate JQuery libraries installed but I wonder if anyone could point me in the direction of how I can either remove the duplicate library in my wordpress installation or produce a work around?

Comment: You can use this https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script

Answer (score -1):

I think you can remove this js https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js?ver=4.8.2.

Comment: The question is 'how I can either remove the duplicate library in my wordpress installation or produce a work around?' not which library.

Comment: i think this issue come in juqery-3.2.1 so he has to remove it

Comment: Yes that might be the case but they would like to know how to remove it... You never explained that to them

Comment: you can add this code function deregister_js() {
wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-3.2.1.min' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'deregister_js' );

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added the script to the page but it doesn't seem to have resolved the issue. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: use this  wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery' )

Comment: Still not working but can i just check that i'm doing this right - am i meant to add this into a script tag into the header of each of my pages where the pop up doesn't load?

Comment: you have to add this in footer.php